# Container managed login page does not render JSF components

Tags: jsf, authentication

I searched for a solution but could not find an answer for my specific issue. I have a login.xhtml page but the JSF tags are not rendered. When I successfully log in, the tags are renderen correctly. so somehow the login.xhtml does not pass through the faces servlet. This seems strange because all is configured correctly. How can I force the login.xhtml to be rendered correctly?

Here is my web.xml portion

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Login.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/eps_template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="body">

    <h2>Hello, please log in:</h2>
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">
        <p>
            <strong><label for="username">Please type your user
                    name: </label> </strong> <input id="username" type="text" name="j_username"
                size="25" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong><label for="password">Please type your
                    password: </label> </strong> <input id="password" type="password" size="15"
                name="j_password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset"
                value="Reset" />
        </p>
    </form>

</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

So the html form is shown correctly, but the template components are not. The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
template="/WEB-INF/templates/eps_template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="body">

    <h2>Hello, please log in:</h2>
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">
        <p>
            <strong><label for="username">Please type your user
                    name: </label> </strong> <input id="username" type="text" name="j_username"
                size="25" />

        </p>
        <p>
            <strong><label for="password">Please type your
                    password: </label> </strong> <input id="password" type="password" size="15"
                name="j_password" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset"
                value="Reset" />
        </p>

    </form>

</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Update 31 January 2012

Configuration:
Glassfish 3.1
Primefaces 3.1
JSF 2.1

I have a index.html page which forwards to home.jsf. But the container notices the user is not logged in so it redirects to login.xhtml.

If I add only the *.jsf to the web.xml, all is working fine but the login.jsf does not render JSF tags.

```
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

If I also add *.xhtml the login.jsf page does render tags but not properly according to the Primefaces skin. When I click submit the jquery.js is printed to the screen.

Here is the complete web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Primefaces -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>5120</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>/****</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>


<!-- security -->

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>epsadmin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML documents</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

Update after answer 2 by BalusC. This is now the complete web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>5120</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>/tempupload</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/errorpages/error403.jsf</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorpages/error404.jsf</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorpages/error500.jsf</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.*******.ApplicationException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpages/error500.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

This is the url I get when pressing the submit button

```
csman/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=3.1-SNAPSHOT
```

This is the output.

```
PrimeFaces={escapeClientId:function(a){return"#"+a ..........etc
```

However, when I press connect to the start URL again, I am successfully directed to the home.jsf page. So the login procedure went OK.

Not that the login.jsf page displays JSF tags but they are not skinned.

Weird?!

Comment: could you please add the jquery reference/declaration for your pages? and does *.html really needs be handled by the FacesServlet?

Comment: I don't have any jquery references, I just use Primefaces. strange right? And if I add *.html (which was just for test) I am forwarded to the primefaces css file.

Comment: try to remove the resource servlet stuff, this seems to be from a primefaces 2.0 guide and is not needed for 3.1. See http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html

Comment: removing the resources does not have any effect. Note that also the redirect I am getting is random, sometimes it is jquery.js, sometimes primefaces.js --> like csman/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have configured your `FacesServlet` to listen on `*.jsf` URLs. So all you need to do is to change the login and error pages to point to exactly that URL.

So, change

```
<form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
```

to

```
<form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
<form-error-page>/error.jsf</form-error-page>
```

Don't forget to *remove* the additional `*.xhtml` URL pattern on the `FacesServlet` as suggested by the other answer. You have a `<security-constraint>` on `*.xhtml` to block the endusers seeing the raw source and this won't work well together. So your `FacesServlet` mapping should have *only* this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

As a different alternative, **replace** the mapping on `*.jsf` by `*.xhtml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and stick to using `*.xhtml` in all URLs/links throughout your website and *remove* the `<security-constraint>` on `*.xhtml`. With a mapping on `*.xhtml` the endusers will never see the raw source anyway. Every single XHTML file will be passed through the `FacesServlet`.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, as per your comment on the other question you seem to have a meta refresh on the index page. This makes little sense. Just add `<welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>` to the `<welcome-file-list>`. This works fine if you've mapped `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`.

Comment: Please describe the symptoms in developer's perspective instead of telling a meaningless "it doesn't work" in the enduser's perspective. Which of the suggested approaches have you tried? Have you also undone the other changes? I am by the way assuming that you're using JSF 2.x because you're using PrimeFaces 2.x, even though you're using JSF 1.x specific context parameters (mapping on `*.xhtml` won't work in JSF 1.x).

Comment: Hi BalusC, I posted my configuration earlier. I used Seam2 a lot so indeed there were some old configuration parts. Later I moved to JSF2. See my new web.xml where I tried out your suggestion

Comment: Okay, your initial problem of the login page not rendering the JSF components is *actually* solved! I understood that it wasn't. The CSS/JS/etc resources not being resolved is a different problem. You've put the admin security constraint on an URL pattern of `/*`. Guess which resources this URL pattern also covers... Right, it covers *everything*. You need to map it on a more specific pattern, e.g. `/app/*` or something so that only the JSF pages are restricted and not the CSS/JS/etc resources.

Comment: Yes, I had it set to *.xhtml, but this has no effect. I have been tweaking on this config a lot so I accidentally posted it

Comment: JSF resources have the same URL pattern so this definitely won't have any effect. You should not put the admin security constraint URL pattern on the same pattern as the `FacesServlet` is listening on. I suggest a folder pattern such as `/app/*` or `/admin/*` or whatever and put the XHTML files in there.

Comment: Ok, I did not see that the security constraint's url-pattern was messing up things, I changed it now accordingly and it works. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Your `login.xhtml` will not be handled by the `FacesServlet`. You only handle `*.jsf` Files.
You need to map `xhtml`, too.

For Servlet-Spec up to 2.4:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For Servlet-Spec 2.5 and up:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Or just use `<form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>`.

Comment: well, it seems not to be working. When I add <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> and click the submit button I am forwarded to the following url http://myserver/myapp/*/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&v=3.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @balusC I already have <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>

Comment: you can't use /* as a pattern, this will catch everything, images, javascript etc and won't work

Comment: Yes, I know, but if I add both *jsf and *.xhtml in the url-patters as suggested earlier, I am forwarded to myapp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3.1-SNAPSHOT and the entire JQuery code is printed to the screen .....

Comment: why do you have a javascript that ends on xhtml?

Comment: I don't ! that's the whole point. :-) I have a standard config of JSF form authentication but it doesn't render JSF tags. Therefore I started this topic.

Comment: 1. simple solution rename your login/error page to login.jsf and leave the configuration to *.jsf OR put all your faces under one directory like /faces/ and change configuration to /faces/*.jsf and /faces/*.xhtml

Comment: one thing I forgot to mention, is the cause if this problem in the index.html page?? I do a forward there. <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=home.xhtml">

Comment: @oers, this doesn't work either, I get an Invalid URL Pattern: [/faces/*.jsf]. tried it with "faces/*.jsf" and "faces/*" and "faces/*.jsf" etc.

Comment: i think i am confused myself right now :) i take that back. i am just wondering why there is a redirect to jquery.js.xhtml, this should not be an xhtml file and because it is called as such is handled by the facesservlet. how do you refer to it?

Comment: Glad I am not the only one confused here ;-) I have spent some hours getting this to work. I will update the question with some more info

Comment: @Coen: you didn't understood me. I posted an answer.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I still have the same problem. I think somehow Glassfish faults the original URL and does a weird redirect after succesful login.