# integration of jsf2.0 and spring 3.1 and hibernate 4.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, tomcat7

i want to integrate jsf2.0 and spring 3.1 and hibernate 4.1. but tomcat has error 404:description The requested resource (/jsfspringhiber/page/default.jsf) is not available.
what is wrong?
[image]
following is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <display-name>jsfspringhiber</display-name>

  <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/default.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: It's not about JSF, Spring or Hibernate. The 404 error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the server could not find what was requested. Show your `web.xml` file. Check your settings of Tomcat.

Comment: @AndreyKapelchik, i add my web.xml. which setting of tomcat i must check?

Comment: @AndreyKapelchik, i added the slash before faces in welcome file list. but it did not solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use maven. the correct answer is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293730/oracle-11g-and-integration-of-hibernate-spring-and-jsf/11295542#11295542)
the structure is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are using eclipse, I think that you have a problem with the deploy.

1) check the tomcat deploy path to see if it is deployed correctly: workspace/.metadata/plugings/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps. (some times help deleting the tmp0, to force tomcat to redeploy).

2) In the project's properties check the deployment assembly and verificy that all the need file are included.

This might work

Comment: i checked tomcat deploy path, it existed and the deployment assembly has two source: 1. /src 2./webcontent

Comment: i deleted the temp0 and defined new server but still i have problem

Comment: are you using maven or something similar?

Comment: have you inclued the "Web App Libraries" in properties->java build path-libraries?

Comment: yes, i have added jar files of spring hibernate and jsf jars.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you have the url-pattern as /faces/* , the Faces servlet will prepend every request with /faces. So you will have to access the resource as /jsfspringhiber/faces/page/default.xhtml or just /jsfspringhiber (if the welcome file is listed as faces/page/default.xhtml).

Update: Remove all the servlet-mappings and just use one:

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>default.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and put the default.xhtml file under WebContent directory.

If you really want to map all those url patterns look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032635/container-managed-login-page-does-not-render-jsf-components)

Comment: right click on default.xhtml and run it on server. but when it runs, in browser converts to http://localhost:7080/jsfspringhiber/default.jsf.

Comment: i putted the default.xhtml in webcontent root.