# oracle 11g and integration of hibernate spring and jsf

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

i am using jsf 2,hibernate 4.1.4,spring 3.1,oracle 11g and maven 3.
but it can not connect to oracle and has error. i downloaded the latest version ojdbc6.
applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

 <!-- Beans Declaration -->
 <bean id="customer" class="model.Customer"/>

<!-- CustomerBo Declaration -->
 <bean id="CustomerBoImpl" class="bo.CustomerBoImpl">
      <property name="customerDaoImpl" ref="CustomerDaoImpl" />
     </bean>


 <!-- Customer DAO Declaration -->
 <bean id="CustomerDaoImpl" class="dao.CustomerDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
 <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@Mohsen-PC:1521:mydb" />
  <property name="user" value="system" />
  <property name="password" value="123" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
 <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>model.Customer</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

 <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

faces-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
<application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>


</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jsfspringhiber</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
          </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>default.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

CustomerDaoImpl.java

```
 public class CustomerDaoImpl implements ICustomerDao{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;}
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
         this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(customer);

    }

    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        sessionFactory.openSession();
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(customer);
    }


    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){
        sessionFactory.openSession();

        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession

().createQuery("from CUSTOMER").list();
        return list;

    }
}
```

CustomerBoImpl.java

```
public class CustomerBoImpl implements ICustomerBo{

    ICustomerDao customerDaoImpl;



    public ICustomerDao getCustomerDaoImpl() {
        return customerDaoImpl;
    }

    public void setCustomerDaoImpl(ICustomerDao customerDaoImpl) {
        this.customerDaoImpl = customerDaoImpl;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

        getCustomerDaoImpl().addCustomer(customer);

    }

    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDaoImpl().updateCustomer(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDaoImpl().deleteCustomer(customer);
    }
    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){

        return getCustomerDaoImpl().findAllCustomer();
    }
}
```

Customermanagedbean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="CustomerMB")
@RequestScoped
public class Customermanagedbean implements Serializable{
@ManagedProperty(value="#{CustomerBoImpl}")
ICustomerBo customerBoImpl;
List<Customer> CustomerList;
public int customerId;
public String name;
public String address;
public String createdDate;



public ICustomerBo getCustomerBoImpl() {
    return customerBoImpl;
}
public void setCustomerBoImpl(ICustomerBo customerBoImpl) {
    this.customerBoImpl = customerBoImpl;
}

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return CustomerList;
}
public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
    CustomerList = customerList;
}
public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}
public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
//add a new customer data into database
public String addCustomer(){

    Customer cust = new Customer();
    cust.setCustomerId(getCustomerId());
    cust.setName(getName());
    cust.setAddress(getAddress());
cust.setCreatedDate(getCreatedDate());
    customerBoImpl.addCustomer(cust);

    clearForm();

    return "";
}

//clear form values
private void clearForm(){
    setName("");
    setAddress("");
}


}
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")

public class Customer{

    public int customerId;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String createdDate;

    @Id
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    @Column(name="NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
}
```

default.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="table-style.css"  />
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <h1>JSF 2.0 + Spring + Hibernate Example</h1>

        <h:dataTable value="#{CustomerMB.getCustomerList()}" var="c"
                styleClass="order-table"
                headerClass="order-table-header"
                rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row"
            >

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Customer ID
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.customerId}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Name
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.name}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Address
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.address}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    Created Date
                </f:facet>
                    #{c.createdDate}
            </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>

        <h2>Add New Customer</h2>
        <h:form>

            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                Customer ID : 
                <h:inputText id="customerId" value="#{CustomerMB.customerId}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="customerId" >
                </h:inputText>

                <h:message for="customerId" style="color:red" />
                Name : 
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{CustomerMB.name}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="Name" >
                </h:inputText>

                <h:message for="name" style="color:red" />

                Address : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="address" value="#{CustomerMB.address}" 
                    cols="30" rows="10" required="true"
                    label="Address" >
                </h:inputTextarea>

                <h:message for="address" style="color:red" />

created Date : 
                <h:inputTextarea id="createdDate" value="#{CustomerMB.createdDate}" 
                    size="20" required="true"
                    label="createdDate" >
                </h:inputTextarea>

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{CustomerMB.addCustomer()}" />

        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

when i run the default.xhtml:
i can not see the records in the table.
[image]

when i click the submit button i have these errors:

```
SEVERE: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1041)
    at dao.CustomerDaoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerDaoImpl.java:18)
    at bo.CustomerBoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerBoImpl.java:23)
    at managedbean.Customermanagedbean.addCustomer(Customermanagedbean.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 24 more

Jul 02, 2012 4:40:48 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{CustomerMB.addCustomer()}: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
javax.faces.FacesException: #{CustomerMB.addCustomer()}: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1041)
    at dao.CustomerDaoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerDaoImpl.java:18)
    at bo.CustomerBoImpl.addCustomer(CustomerBoImpl.java:23)
    at managedbean.Customermanagedbean.addCustomer(Customermanagedbean.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a Hibernate session available. So, you need to call `SessionFactory.openSession()`, before you do `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: @BheshGurung, i added the SessionFactory.openSession() in to my codes. but i did not work.(edit the above)

Comment: @ElijahSaounkine, what shall i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional in my CustomerBoImpl.java

```
import java.util.List;
import bo.ICustomerBo;
import dao.ICustomerDao;
import model.Customer;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomerBoImpl implements ICustomerBo{

    ICustomerDao customerDaoImpl;



    public ICustomerDao getCustomerDaoImpl() {
        return customerDaoImpl;
    }

    public void setCustomerDaoImpl(ICustomerDao customerDaoImpl) {
        this.customerDaoImpl = customerDaoImpl;
    }

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

        getCustomerDaoImpl().addCustomer(customer);

    }

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDaoImpl().updateCustomer(customer);
    }

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
@Override
    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDaoImpl().deleteCustomer(customer);
    }

@Override
    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){

        return getCustomerDaoImpl().findAllCustomer();
    }
}
```